# Should I move this van der Waals equation/atmospheric CO2 question elsewhere?

Tags: discussion

I wonder if the question [ppmV versus μmol/mol for atmospheric CO2](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/10157/6031) might do better in Chemistry or Physics SE. The science behind the answer probably will need the correction to the ideal gas law as expressed in [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) or [van der Waals Equation of State](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/waal.html#c1) as applied to mixtures of non-ideal gasses.

But the simplest answer could be just a conversion factor close to 1.0 which would be close enough for me for now.

Any thoughts?

**edit:** I've just won a "Tumbleweed" with this question! :) I've also added a `+50` bounty on the original question. If still no luck, I'll either ask for migration, or just delete and repost.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite being late, the question was eventually answered & accepted.

You might have got a more prompt answer on the other sites you refer to, it's difficult to know.

I guess it shows that some members of this site don't visit too often, or there aren't many members qualified to answer the question, or they may just have been too busy when the question was posted.

Comment: It's a well written, [definitive answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/10367/6031), and it was worth the wait. Good things come to those who use stackexchange!